# Why does it show Invalid color value ?attr/textcolor Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors

I'm trying to build a Generated signed bundle in Android Studio but it doesn't work. It shows this error message.

270 exceptions were raised by workers:
A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$RunnableWrapperWorkAction
A failure occurred while executing
(and much longer)

Invalid color value ?attr/textcolor

This is my code below

```
 <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24">
  <path
      android:pathData="M18,6L6,18"
      android:strokeLineJoin="round"
      android:strokeWidth="2.5"
      android:fillColor="#00000000"
      android:strokeColor="?attr/textcolor"
      tools:ignore="VectorRaster"
      android:strokeLineCap="round"/>
  <path
      android:pathData="M6,6L18,18"
      tools:ignore="VectorRaster"
      android:strokeLineJoin="round"
      android:strokeWidth="2.5"
      android:fillColor="#00000000"
      android:strokeColor="?attr/textcolor"
      android:strokeLineCap="round"/>
</vector>
```

Comment: you can add your textcolor to colors.xml in resource. Or try something like `?attr/color:red`

Comment: Hello, Thanks but it doesn't work, comes up as red.

Comment: does error occur in all xml when using `@color/yourColor` ?

Comment: Hello, I fixed it. I used the hex colour instead. But I'm using a template for my app but whenever I add an Image asset in Res folder, it makes the ?attr/textcolor thing. It knows that it is a colour but it doesn't work. But if I don't add a image asset it works for some reason.

Comment: but keep in mind, using hard code hex is not recommended

Comment: What do you mean? I thought hex colour was the main colour for java.

Comment: Yes but I recomend to put all your hex color in file `res/color.xml`. But you say that you cannot use `@color/yourColor` ? That's mean you use hard code right

Comment: Also when I refractor a folder under java to change the name like com.example.example to com.test.test. It says that for example R.id.policy. The r. is not identified or something.

Comment: move cursor to `R` then `alt + enter` and import class, choose your package name. Example `com.test.test`